# malloc(): corrupted top size, but I am using delete[]

Tags: c++

```cpp
void merge_sort(int* arr, int start, int stop){ // [start; stop]
    int min_array_size = 8;

    std::cout << start << " " << stop << std::endl;

    if ((stop - start + 1) > min_array_size){
        merge_sort(arr, start, start + ((stop-start+1) / 2) - 1);
        merge_sort(arr, start + ((stop-start+1) / 2), stop);

        std::cout << "merging: " << start << " " << stop << std::endl;

        int left_index = start;
        int right_index = start + ((stop-start+1) / 2);

        int* new_arr = new int[stop-start + 1];

        std::cout << "New_arr created!\n";

        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++){
            if (arr[left_index] < arr[right_index]){
                new_arr[i] = arr[left_index];
                left_index++;
            }
            else {
                new_arr[i] = arr[right_index];
                right_index++;
            }

            if (left_index == start + ((stop-start+1) / 2)){
                i++;
                for (int j = i; j <= stop; j++, i++){
                    new_arr[j] = arr[right_index++];
                }
            }
            if (right_index > stop){
                i++;
                for (int j = i; j <= stop; j++, i++){
                    new_arr[j] = arr[left_index++];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++){
            arr[i] = new_arr[i];
            std::cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << std::endl;
        }

        delete[] new_arr;

        std::cout << "memory cleaned!\n";

    }
    else{
        selection_sort(arr + start, (stop - start + 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < (stop - start) + 1; i++){
            std::cout << arr[i + start] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why it says the following if I clean memory with `delete[] new_arr`?

> malloc(): corrupted top size

I really can't understand why it is so.

Here is my `insertion_sort()` code:

```cpp
void selection_sort(int* arr, size_t size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        int min_index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_index]){
                min_index = j;
            }
        }
        if (min_index != i){
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[min_index]);
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Wj56MM349

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Then most, if not all of your issues go away.  If not go away entirely, at least you can use `at()` to determine if you are going out of bounds.

Comment: `new` is generally a wrapper to a call to `malloc`, so that is why you are getting an error for `malloc` even without calling it yourself.  What you are seeing is that you are writing outside the bounds of the array you created.

Comment: but why doesn`t new[ ] work?

Comment: where is `selection_sort`? I can't compile your code.

Comment: @Proger2.0 -- *but why doesn't new[ ] work?* -- The `new[]` works just fine.  No different than asking "why doesn't my hammer work?" when you built the furniture incorrectly, and there is nothing wrong with the hammer.

Comment: no, man. it says i have error in this line of code:

int *new_arr = new int[....
it cant create a new array

Comment: Print out the values of `stop` and `start` so you can confirm that `stop-start + 1 > 0`

Comment: @Proger2.0 `int* new_arr = new int[stop-start + 1];` -- Do you know what the value of `stop - start + 1` is?

Comment: Can't reproduce error you are reporting: https://godbolt.org/z/nzqv6ehd7 (it doesn't work at all) please provide [mcve].

Comment: yes, it is was exactly start = 0, stop = 31

Comment: Full code here: https://pastebin.com/c8tF44QW

Comment: @Proger2.0 No, post the code here.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/8rMdchxsr

Comment: ok, this is the code of insertion_sort:

'''
    void selection_sort(int* arr, size_t size){
 for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        int min_index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_index]){
                min_index = j;
            }
        }
        if (min_index != i){
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[min_index]);
        }
    }
}
'''

Comment: @Proger2.0 Please post the code in the original post, not in the comment section.

Comment: Ok now I can see a problem: https://godbolt.org/z/Wj56MM349

Comment: Can u explain why it is an error? i still cant understand

Comment: Ok, maybe the heap is to small... maybe i should call less recursive functions... i think i should have set int min_array_size to a larger value...

Comment: One of the great horrors of any programming language is a bug can mortally wound a program and the program will keep staggering along, finally falling down and dying or otherwise showing signs of the bug, far, far away from where the bug is and usually somewhere totally innocent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overflowing your heap allocations, corrupting the heap, and breaking things eventually. The problem is:

1. You allocate an array with `stop - start + 1` elements (meaning valid indices run from `0` to `stop - start`.
2. In the subsequent loop (`for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++){`), you *assign* to any and all array indices from `start` to `stop` (inclusive on both ends).

If `start` is not `0`, then assignment to `new_arr[stop]` is definitely an out-of-bounds write; the larger `start` gets, the more invalid indices you'll see.

The problem would rarely occur as a result of a single call (the heap metadata being corrupted would be for a subsequent heap element, not the one containing `new_arr`), but with the recursive calls you have plenty of opportunities to do terrible things to the heap and break it faster. Even a single such out-of-bounds write puts you in nasal demons territory, so you need to fix your code to avoid doing it even once.

Comment: Sorry, but i cant agree with you. I managed to fix my problem by increasing min_arr_size to a larger value... so the number of recursive calls becomes little. There are no problems with algo... it`s me calling recursive functions too often

Comment: @Proger2.0 there is definately issue with out of bounds indexing, which means you have UB in your code. Consequences of UB could vary dramatically.

Comment: @Proger2.0 -- [Here is your code](https://godbolt.org/z/oeGE7eWca), but using `std::vector` and using `at()` to prove that your conclusions are wrong, and you really didn't fix the problem.  When a coding change is made, you need to know *why* the problem existed.  If you look at the `at()` call, it is on the line `new_arr.at(i) = arr.at(right_index);` where it used to be `new_arr[i] = arr[right_index];`.  The vector gives you bounds checking, and will throw an exception when you go out-of-bounds, just like it says in the output.

Comment: @Proger2.0: Increasing `min_array_size` means you go through the code with out-of-bounds writes less often, and only for larger inputs. If you do it infrequently enough, and go small enough amounts out-of-bounds, you might get lucky and only write to "slack memory" (memory that's not officially part of the allocation, but which, thanks to the allocator rounding off allocation sizes, is "safe" to stomp on). You've *hidden* the problem and/or reduced the occurrences to the point where you're getting lucky, you haven't eliminated it.